# How to read Excel (.xlsx) file in java?

Tags: java, android, excel, apache-poi

From a given `.xlsx` file, I am trying to read data using Java.

[image]

My code for reading the file is as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("E:\\test1.xlsx"));
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
        XSSFSheet test = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        student emp = new student();
        Iterator<Row> itr = test.iterator();
        itr.next();
        while(itr.hasNext()){
               Row row = itr.next();
               emp.reedData(row);
               System.out.println(id+","+name+","+options);
        }
```

The method is as follows:

```
void reedData(Row row){
    id= row.getCell(0).toString();
    name= row.getCell(1).toString();
    options= row.getCell(2).toString();
}
```

But, I am getting output like this:

```
1.0,X,play game
,,sing song
2.0,Y,play game
,,sing song
```

Instead of the above, I want the output to look like this:

```
1.0,X,{play game,sing song}
2.0,Y,{play game,sing song}
```

This problem is because I am merging two cells in `.xlsx` file.

Any suggestion?
thank you in advance..

Comment: You need to read both Rows that make up your options column for every multirow that are your other columns.

Answer (score 4):

This is how I did it.

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.IndexedColors;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public  class  read {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        FileInputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream(new File(keep));
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile);
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

        int rowCount; // number of rows of newly form excel files 
        rowCount= sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
        out.println(rowCount);

        //trying to iterate the excel file
        int i =0;
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator     = sheet.iterator();
         do{
            Row row = rowIterator.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            while(cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                if(cell.getColumnIndex()==0) { // to read the first column 
                    DataFormatter df = new DataFormatter();
                    String str2      = df.formatCellValue(cell);
                    customerNo.add(str2);
                }
            }
            ++i;
            if(i>rowCount)break;
            //break;
        }while(rowIterator.hasNext());
        wb.close();
   }
}
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using Apache POI.
Try merging these 2 cells in your code with:

```
test.addMergedRegion(1,2,0,0);
```

or:

```
sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(1,2,0,0))
```